# Flutter iOS Chromecast doesn't request for NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription

Tags: ios, flutter, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a problem with a flutter app, whenever I call **GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().presentCastDialog()** the cast device popup shows, it says to check settings to make sure that Local Network Access is on, but there is no popup to request **NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription** permission from the user and never appears.

I am using **'google-cast-sdk', '~> 4.7.0'**

I've already added **com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info** to the Entitlements.

Also added the necesary fields into Info.plist

```
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_googlecast._tcp</string>
    <string>_CC1AD845._googlecast._tcp</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>App uses the local network to discover Cast-enabled devices on your WiFi network.</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>App uses Bluetooth to discover nearby Cast devices.</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>App uses Bluetooth to discover nearby Cast devices.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>App uses microphone access to listen for ultrasonic tokens when pairing with nearby Cast devices.</string>
```

I am using CC1AD845 for NSBonjourServices because that's the Default Media Receiver Application ID.

It is a bit strange because the **NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription** popup shows and that **NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription** doesn't show in settings and at all in the app.

Does anyone have any tips what I should do next in order for the **NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription** request dialog to appear?